# Restart iPhone after installing or upgrading an app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

What's the logic behind it? Ive been told by multiple apps to do this.

I've also noticed that if I reinstall/build the app too many times from xcode, it will become unstable and more likely to crash. A restart does fix the problems.

Comment: You may also ask, why Windows always wants this...

Comment: Odd. I've been writing iphone apps for 3 years now, and I have never noticed this. I have noticed a few cases where the sim becomes unstable, and you need to restart, but never the device. Can you give us some more info on this?

Comment: I meant restart the iPhone not OS X. I just encountered this problem again using instrument's leak tool.

Comment: You're not explaining the problem, just the effect... If you're talking about iOS killing your app because instruments is taking too long to get going? Yeah that happens, its instruments fault, nobody elses. If restarting your phone makes it work better, that's purely coincidence.

Comment: if i knew what caused the problem I wouldn't be asking. when it crashes it shows the apple logo for a few seconds then the lock screen. a manual restart fixes the problem, until running instrument again (this doesn't always happen)

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Create a small project with some reproducible effects, and file a bug, as has been suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the logic behind it? Ive been
>   told by multiple apps to do this.

What apps? I haven't seen this yet myself, but I would guess that, if true, it might have something to do with the multitasking in iOS 4.0 and apps maybe not being quit if already running before an update. But it's strange.

> I've also noticed that if I
>   reinstall/build the app too many times
>   from xcode, it will become unstable
>   and more likely to crash. A restart
>   does fix the problems.

Really, this sounds like a bit of folk science. Occasionally, a device can go a bit whacko, but that used to happen to me in (say) the days of 2.2.1.  So if you can honestly reproduce this issue, I strongly encourage you to [file a bug with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com/) and get it fixed. Note they will probably ask you for a reproducible sample project in order to prove out this theory.